# Node-RED installed on Google Cloud Platform, but "Error: Lost connection to server"

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, node-red

I installed and deploy Node-RED on Google Cloud Console by using Node.js on Google Cloud Platform.
Then I can see the display of Node-RED, control nodes, and deploy. But always display "Error: Lost connection to server", and not work properly.
In the case of Bluemix, it can work by connecting on https, but cannot work on https.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like there is a problem creating a Websocket connection. Any config options for GCC to do with Websockets?

Answer (score 0):

Google App Engine doesn't support websockets over secure connection at the moment, if you still want it to work over google cloud platform, you will need to change the node red to open its websocket connection directly to the machine external ip and use it over http connection only